# Communicate between computers through Ethernet cable

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, win-universal-app

I want to connect two computers with an Ethernet cable **without the user having to set up a LAN through the Control Panel** and then transfer data between two instances of my app - one running on each computer.

As soon as I have a connection with an IP address for each computer, I know I can <s>easily</s> transfer a file by using Sockets, Pipes(?), WCF... But both computers are also connected via wifi to a router, so how can I somehow tell the computer that for a specific IP address - please use the cable? (I might be getting all of this wrong. Please feel free to correct me.)

I can use a UWP app or a .net (Winform/WPF) app. Either technology is fine. But this must be done in code, not by the users setting up a LAN through the Control Panel. Also, IPv6 is fine too.

Comment: To use  WebClient the other computer needs to run a webserver first. I think you'll have to use sockets.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thanks.  That sounds sound. I'll edit that. Any idea about setting up the connection, though?

Comment: maybe **socket**? i cannot imagin an OP with so many scores asking such questions

Answer (score 1):

Each network card has its own IP address, so both of the computers will have IP address for the WIFI network and another IP address for the ad-hoc link.
The addresses for the ad-hoc link can be set to an address in one IP segment, for example, 10.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.2, if the WIFI addresses are in the range of 192.168.X.X.
Your OS will know which card is related to each IP segment.

Comment: are you talking about C#?

Comment: he is talking about hardware

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, he asked how to tell the computer to use one network (the ad-hoc network) and not the other (the wifi network). It has nothing to do with C# as the OS (or router) is dealing with it using routing tables.

Comment: @TalDelbari I'm not sure what you're suggesting. Let's take this step by step - I connect the cable to both computers. Now what?

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Connect-Two-Computers-Together-with-an-Ethernet-Cable

After you set the ad-hoc network both of the computers will have their own IP addresses (in addition to the other IP addresses they already have for the wifi network)

Comment: @TalDelbari Perhaps you missed my edit - `this must be done in code, not by the users setting up a LAN through the Control Panel.`.

Comment: so this is why i say he's not talking about C#

Comment: (You need to add `@ispiro` to your comment for me to get notified of it.

Answer (score 1):

Start with `System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()`.

Filter out the Type=EtherNet interfaces and make sure they're Up. You may also have to watch out for virtual adapters etc.

From the selected adapter you can get Address Information etc. The IPV4 address should probably be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks. So you're saying I don't have to deal with the computers recognizing each other. That that will be automatic?

Comment: I tried this but though I do have one `NetworkInterface` of type `NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet` - its `OperationalStatus` is `OperationalStatus.Down` despite the cable being connected to both computers. Do I need to enable it somehow? I even see in `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections` that it's `unplugged` on both computers (though it's physically plugged in).

Comment: check the cable type(you need some special calbe to directly connect two pc, though some latest OS can tolerant this), and also check ip config, to set them to the same network, as @Tal Delbari has said.

Comment: I haven't done this in a long time. Modern adapters should be auto-detect but for older hardware you may need a special cross-over cable.  Usually black with red plugs. Buying a small switch (/ router) may turn out to be cheaper and more reliable.

Comment: You can tell if you have the right cable by looking a the little lights next to the cable sockets. Maybe not with laptops but as soon as 1 side shows/blinks green you have a lot better chance to get it working.